# Finding arc length of the curve $6xy=x^4+3$ from $x=1$ to $x=2$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Looking at this as a graph of a function of $y$ is more convenient 
$$
y=\frac{x^4+3}{6x}\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3-1}{2x^2}\Rightarrow  \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2=\frac{x^6-2x^3+1}{4x^4}
$$
And the integral for arc length:
$$
\int_1^2 \sqrt{1+\frac{x^6-2x^3+1}{4x^4}} \, \mathrm dx=\int_1^2 \frac{1}{2x^2}
\sqrt{4x^4+x^6-2x^3+1} \, \mathrm dx
$$
Which I am not sure how to evaluate. Substitutions don't seem fruitful and integration by parts looks like it will be messy. Did I set things up wrong? Is there an easy way to evaluate this integral?

edit: As Dr. MV pointed out, I made a differentiation error which he corrects below.

Comment: Let's just wait for Cleo to answer this...

Comment: @KennyLau It would be an honor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$1+y'^2(x)=\frac14\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Why does your expression have 3 terms while the OP's has 4?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that your expression for $y'(x)$ has a typo.  $$y'(x)=\frac12x^2-\frac12 x^{-2}$$

Comment: @KennyLau The expression in the OP is incorrect.

Comment: Oh oops, thanks again! I am realizing this is the way these usually shake out

Comment: You're welcome again.